# upload a file via a form using ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, asp-classic, vbscript

I have a simple html form in a .asp page. I would like add a field to let users upload files via the form on my server/ftp on the fly. Any suggestions on how I can do this please?

this is the code I am using for the HTML

```
<form name="formUpload" id="formUpload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<table valign="top" align="left" bgcolor="PaleGoldenRod" width="300px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr bgcolor="PaleGoldenRod" valign="top">
    <td width="300px">
        <input type="file" size="50" name="file1">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload File">
    </td>
</tr></table></form>
```

I have no idea how to do this because I never had done something like this.

Comment: You can use [code I have written in the past](http://forums.aspfree.com/code-bank-54/pure-asp-upload-script-with-additional-features-94647.html) it's explained in much details and the thread contains lots of useful tips.

Comment: @Rene have you solved your problem? Was one of the answers the solution for you? If so, could you tag one?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following jQuery plugin to handle 'on the fly' uploads:

[jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

But like Symeon said, you will need an ASP Classic component that will handle the file uploads on the server. I used the [FreeASPUpload](http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/viewsource.asp) version a couple of times, works like a breeze.

Comment: I ve tried this script... it is working great :) one question i have. i am uploaded the files in /upload folder. In the form i have an name field which the users fills in and submits. I want that the files being uploaded from the users will save themselves into this path /upload/David (example) instead of just /upload.... like that I can identify who uploaded the files.. is it difficult to do please?

Comment: Upload the files to /upload and after that move the file to the correct directory, using the value from the form field. U can use the [Scripting.FileSystemObject](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_filesystem.asp) for this.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP you have to write your own upload handler to take the http stream and write it to disk - there is plenty of example code on the web. I have some, but it is a bit big to post here.

Look at [this](http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/viewsource.asp)   or [this](http://www.motobit.com/help/scptutl/upload.asp)

HTH

Comment: maybe there is an easier way with jquery?

Comment: Jquery is client only - you still need a mechanism on the server to accept a stream of data and write it to disk - you can either do this via http and use ASP to accept the stream (or use ASP.NET which has the code built in, or infact php etc) or you need an ftp server and get jquery to send the data to an ftp server.